# Does anyone know what this matrix is?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I am supposed to obtain this matrix determinant, but I'm intrigued by its symetry. Does this matrix mean something in particular?

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & B_3 & -B_2 & -iE_1 \\
    -B_3 & 0 & D_1 & -iE_2 \\
    B_2 & -D_1 & 0 & -iE_3 \\
    iE_1 & iE_2 & iE_3 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

This looks like something to do with electromagnetism, is $D_1$ a component of the electric displacement?

Comment: It looks a bit like the electromagnetic field tensor (eqn. 12.119 in Griffiths E&M, 4th ed.), often denoted $F^{\mu\nu}$. But the correspondence is nowhere near exact. I have also seen some textbooks combine the electric and magnetic fields into one complex vector; perhaps this is related to that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor It’s strange to have $D_1$ instead of $E_1$. Are you sure? Your tensor has the time components in the last row and column instead of the first. The $i$’s are probably because the spacetime coordinates are being taken as $(x, y, z, i t)$ rather than $(t,x,y,z)$.

Comment: Reference to quoted matrix?

Comment: Sadly there is no reference, it does look a lot like that tensor. I guess I'll ask next week. I will share the answer here.